# Find last two digits of a number $A=(2016^{2015^{2014}}+2014^{2015^{2016}}+2017)^{2017}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find last two digits of a number $A=(2016^{2015^{2014}}+2014^{2015^{2016}}+2017)^{2017}$.

I have tried to write $A=100k+r$ and find r in $A$ but I stuck at it. Any solution will be aprreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try to mod 4 and mod 25 and use CRT to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

We work below modulo $100$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
A
&=\left(\ 2016^{2015^{2014}}+2014^{2015^{2016}}+2017\right)^{2017}
\\
&=\left(\ 16^{2015^{2014}}+14^{2015^{2016}}+17\right)^{2017}
\\
&=\left(\ 
 16^{2015^{2014}\text{ taken modulo }5}
+14^{2015^{2016}\text{ taken modulo }10}
+17\right)^{2017}
\\
&\qquad\text{ since $16^1=16^{1+5}$ and $14^2=14^{2+10}$, both modulo hundred}
\\
&\qquad\text{ and we have periodic repetitons after $16^1$ and $14^2$ with periods $5,10$}
\\
&=\left(\ 
 16^{5}
+14^{5}
+17\right)^{2017}
\\
&=\left(\ 
 76
+24
+17\right)^{2017}
=17^{2017}
\\
&=17^{2017\text{ taken modulo }40=\phi(100)}
\\
&= 17^{17}=77\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
All equalities hold in $\Bbb Z/100$.

Comment: How do we know the periodic repetitions after $16^1$ and $14^2$ with periods 5 and 10? Do we have to prove it ?

Comment: @NguyenThy To show $\,16^{\large 5k+1}\equiv 16\pmod{100},\,$ i.e. that $\,100\mid n = 16(16^{\large 5k}-1),\,$ note $\bmod 25\!:\,\ 16^{\large 5k}\equiv (2^4)^{\large 5k}\equiv 2^{\large 20k}\equiv 1\,$ by Euler & $\phi(25)=20.\,$ Also $\,4\mid 16\mid  n\,$ so $\,4\cdot 25 = 100\mid n.\,$ Similarly for $\,m = 14^2(14^{\large 10k}-1)\,$ via $\bmod 25\!:\ 14\equiv 8^2\,$ so $\,14^{\large 10k}\equiv 8^{\large 20k}\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,25\mid m.\ \ $

Comment: @NguyenThy Yes, we have to show, or at least mention $16^1=16^6$ and $14^2=14^12$ modulo $100$. I decided only to mention these (as i saw the $17^{17}$), since a simple calculator can do the job, or even working with bare hands as  Bill Dubuque did, thanks!, or $16^1(1-16^5)=16(1-\binom 506^5-\binom 51 6^4\cdot 10)= 16(1-6^5)=16(1-(1+5)^5)=\dots=0$. Same for $14^2-14^{12}=0$. Modulo $4$ it is clear. Modulo $25$ we have $14^{10}=(15-1)^{10}=1-\binom{10}1\cdot 15=1$. All this is simpler than that $17^{17}$, which in a competition, without computer, i would do also using binomial expansions.

Comment: @dan_fulea How do you propose to compute $17^{17}$ by binomial expansion?

Comment: @BillDubuque We know $17^{40}=1$, so we compute first $17^{20}=\pm 1$, this is more exactly $(20-3)^{20}=3^{20}-\binom {20}1\cdot 20\cdot 3^{19}=3^{20}=9^{10}=(10-1)^10=1-10\cdot 10=1=+1$. So $17^{17}=17^{-3}=53^3=(50+3)^3=27+50=77$. Alternatively, directly, $17^{17}=(20-3)^{17}=-3^{17}+17\cdot 20\cdot 3^{16}=3^{16}\cdot 37=(10-1)^8\cdot 37=(1-80)\cdot 37=21\cdot 37=777=77$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation mod 100, then we get $(16^{2015^{2014}}+14^{2015^{2016}}+17)^{2017}$. Now $16^6 = 16 mod(100)$, and power of 14 recycle after 10 times. so we have to consider the powers of 16 mod 5 and powers of 14 mod 10 and taking considerations of the first terms.

by $(16^5+14^5+17)^{2017}(mod100)=(76+24+17)^{2017}=17^{2017}$. Now order of 17 is 20 in mod 100 and 2017 is 17 mod 100 so $17^{17}=77$ mod 100

Comment: I noticed that $2015^{2014} \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, can I get $A \equiv (16^0+14^5+17)^{2017} \pmod{100}$?

Comment: Ya I see that $16$ divides 100 hence not invertible mod 100. So $16^0=1$ can't apply here. But the powers circles back every 5 steps. So we can do $16^{2015^{2014}-1+1}=16*16^{2015^{2014}-1}=16*16^4$. And we know 16^4 mod 100 so we can multiply it by 16 to get the result...

Comment: The final sentence is incorrect.

Comment: is it correct now??

Comment: It seems to be exactly the same as the answer 16 minutes prior by dan_fulea.

Comment: This is because this is the only way to do it...

Comment: But duplication is very bad for the site. And it is not the only way.

Comment: How do you know (and what do you mean) that "14 recycle after 10 times"? In fact $\,14^{10+n}\not\equiv 14^n\,$ for $\, n = 0,1\ \ $